# Whats the fastest way to sum up an Interger List

Tags: java, list

I was trying to find out whats the fastest way to sum up a list of integers.

First of all i created a method which provides sampledata:

```
public static List<Integer> getIntList(int size) {
    LinkedList<Integer> sampleList = new LinkedList<>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    rand.ints(size).forEach((num)-> sampleList.add(num));
    return sampleList;
}
```

Then i have tryed some different ways to sum up the List.
First of all the worst one:

```
public static void sumUpWithForLoop(List<Integer> data) {
    System.out.println("For-loop:");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int listLenght = data.size();
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listLenght; i++) {
        total += data.get(i);
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Result: " + total);
    System.out.println("Duration: " + (end - start) + "ms");
}
```

After running this class i have noticed, that it is really slow because it always uses `get(index)` which takes pretty long.

Because of that i tryed to sum up the List with an Iterator

```
public static void sumUpWithItterator(List<Integer> data) {
    System.out.println("Iterator:");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int total = 0;
    for (Integer num : data) {
        total += num;
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Result: " + total);
    System.out.println("Duration: " + (end - start) + "ms");
}
```

This method is the fastest way to sum up a Integer-List so far but I am still trying to find a faster one.
I also tryed to use `.stream()` and `.parallelStream()`:

```
 public static void sumUpWithNormalStream(List<Integer> data) {
    System.out.println("Stream");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int total = data.stream().mapToInt(num -> num).sum();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Result: " + total);
    System.out.println("Duration: " + (end - start) + "ms");
}
public static void sumUpWithParallelStream(List<Integer> data) {
    System.out.println("ParallelStream");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int total = data.parallelStream().mapToInt(num->num).sum();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Result: " + total);
    System.out.println("Duration: " + (end - start) + "ms");
}
```

The normal `stream`is nearly as fast as the Iterator, while the `parallelStream`is much slower than the Iterator. I guess that this is caused by the overhead of the parallelisation and the fact that summing up a List is an operation that runs pretty fast and doesn't have to wait for things like database-operations.

All in all I am still not happy with the current method but i haven't found a faster one yet. 
Do you have any ideas what could be faster then a normal Iterator for summing up a List.

Thank you for your sugestions.

Comment: Adding numbers is dirt cheap. All your time is spent chasing pointers, creating temporary objects and calling intermediate functions. Try using `ArrayList<Integer>` or even `int[]` - it should be much faster.

Comment: The fastest one is native method.

Comment: Does it need to be `Integer`s ? can't you use an array of `int` for example to prevent the cost of auto-unboxing?

Comment: The relative speed of these methods is going to depend entirely on the performance of the List methods, which depends on the List implementation. Make sure you test with the appropriate implementations. 'get(i)' is constant time on `ArrayList`, but O(n) on `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example memory access is probably bottleneck, because adding integer is very fast operation, but accessing next element of linked list requires two memory accesses (one for getting next node and second for accessing integer value - type erasure makes is impossible to use unboxed value). Keep also in mind that linked list is probably scattered over memory, so there is high probability of cache miss.

So to make it faster you should reduce memory access overhead. Change from LinkedList to ArrayList would remove single access (to random location in memory). Change from ArrayList to raw array would remove second one, because in this case unboxed integers will be stored in memory.

Thus version based on `int[]` should be fastest (however less flexible than `ArrayList<Integer>` version).

Answer (score 2):

Using `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of `LinkedList<integer>` will probably give you better results. And since accessing elements one by one is fastest when those elements are stored adjacent to each other on the RAM, try using `int[]`.

In general, if you want to boost the performance of any program, try replacing any function calls or high level code with iterations and low level code. That should enhance the performance significantly.